# Ionic framework login with google redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-signin, google-oauth

I am using `ngCordova` for google authentication in my app.

Problem is after entering email and password it give me `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

I know i have to set redirect uri in google developer console.
i already did it as shown in image.

[image: uri setup]

But don't know why still it is giving me error

How can i make it works?

Comment: What is the plugin you are using for google authentication in your app? Is it **satellizer**?

Comment: I am using this http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/    Login is working fine. but problem is in redirection after login

Comment: Are you testing your app in mobile or browser?

Comment: I am testing in Device.

Comment: Try adding one more redirect URI: `http://localhost/`

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya - Did you found any solution? I'm Facing same problem..

Comment: i tried as per [this example](https://github.com/anilkumar007/google-login) and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `redirect_uri : 'http://localhost/'` propery as a parameter:

```
$cordovaOauth.google("CLIENT_ID_HERE", ["email"],{
                 redirect_uri : 'http://localhost/'
              }).then(function(result) {
            }, function(error) {
            });
```

And add one more redirect URI `http://localhost/` in addition to `http://localhost/callback` in google developer console. I hope it works.

In case it isn't working, if possible use [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) AngularJS plugin  to achieve Google authentication. It is very simple to use and you can pass custom options like redirect_uri.

Comment: Thanks! Adding 3rd parameter worked for me. Didn't find any online document mentioning this parameter. Please share related document link if u have.